# How can I Display data labels with Chart.js using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, requirejs

I am hoping to keep things simple by storing the required files on the server hosting my webapp. I am using the latest version of Chart.js and the data label plugin. The data label file is in the same location as the chart.js called chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js.

```
require(['/file/swiftM/resources/js/chart.umd.js'], function(Chart){
    const ctx = document.getElementById('simple-bar-canvas-ba22');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [13, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This code works but anytime I try to add in the additional requirement of the datalabels.js file I get multiple errors relating to a helper file?

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: chart.js/helpers
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
> at C (require.min.js?version=1691009104058:8:252)
> at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.min.js?version=1691009104058:29:514)

However if I bring in the helper.js file I get an error because it begins with export...

Tried adding in datalabels following existing documentation but I keep receiving errors.